# Is it necessary to have a return statement out side the for loop? with return outside for, i got no error

Tags: c

```
char* kangaroo(int x1, int v1, int x2, int v2) {
    
    int i,k1,k2;
     for(i=0;i<10001;i++)
     {
         k1=x1+(v1*i);
         k2=x2+(v2*i);
         if(k1==k2)
         {
             return "YES";
             break;
         }
         if(i>=10000)
         {
            return "NO";
            break;
         }
         
         
     }
     //return "YES";

}

// error i got-Solution.c: In function ‘kangaroo’:
//Solution.c:71:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
```

Comment: It looks like it's possible for the two conditions within the `for` loop to not be met, meaning a final return statement is required. Is the final `return` supposed to be commented out?

Comment: Just as a side note: Having a `break` statement immediately after an unconditional `return` statement does not make sense, as the `break` statement will never be executed.

Comment: `if(i>=10000)` - What is the point of this?

Comment: I don't think you can exit the loop without entering the second `if` before. The compiler might just not realize that. But otoh what is the point of repeatedly checking the exit condition within the loop if you can just put it after the loop? That's wasting time and makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes all the possible program paths have to lead to the return statement if function is returning a value. Otherwise, it invokes the Undefined Behaviour.

I personally prefer (if possible) function to have one `return` statement at the end of its body.

```
char* kangaroo(int x1, int v1, int x2, int v2) 
{
     char *result = "I do not know";
     int i,k1,k2;
     for(i=0;i<10001;i++)
     {
         k1=x1+(v1*i);
         k2=x2+(v2*i);
         if(k1==k2)
         {
             result = "YES";
             break;
         }
         if(i>=10000)
         {
            result = "NO";
            break;
         }    
     }
     return result;
}
```

IMO it is one of the very few circumstances where `goto` is OK to jump to the epilogue of the function (not the internal one but written by the programmer)

Example(stolen from the kernel coding style):

```
int fun(int a)
{
        int result = 0;
        char *buffer;

        buffer = kmalloc(SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!buffer)
        {
                result = -ENOMEM;
                goto out_;
        }

        if (condition1) {
                while (loop1) {
                        ...
                }
                result = 1;
                goto out_free_buffer;
        }
        ...
out_free_buffer:
        kfree(buffer);
out_:
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, yes, you never want a non-void function to end without a return value. It's bad form and invokes undefined behavior. It might "happen" to work but you should not rely on that.

One alternative is to break out of the loop when you find the result you want, and then return based on whether you exhausted the loop. Some people prefer that approach. Others feel you should return as soon as you know you have the result you want, at least as long as you don't have to do any cleanup. So you could either do:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10001; i++) {
    if (x1 + v1 * i == x2 + v2 * i)
        break;
}
return i >= 10001 ? "NO" : "YES";
```

or:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10001; i++) {
    if (x1 + v1 * i == x2 + v2 * i)
        return "YES";
}
return "NO";
```

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, whether the inputs are always positive, or whether you care about the results when `i == 0`, it may be easier to simply return whether `v1 == v2 && x1 == x2`.

Comment: Err, well, that's what I meant by "default or implied return value" though I agree "default" was the wrong word. By "default" I meant "the thing that happens when you didn't do what you should have done" which is, of course, undefined behavior.

Comment: @sj95126 ***`Generally, yes, you never want a non-void function to end without a return value; even if you are OK with using whatever the default or implied return value might be, it's bad form.`*** No it is vary bad. It is Undefined Behaviour!!!!!

Comment: @sj95126 I removed all my comments and converted them to a +1 after your edit.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the compiler can tell that your `if(i>=10000)` prevents the `for` loop from exiting... unless you made a mistake in your logic. But not all compilers will do that. At the end of the day, every possible execution path through your code must reach a `return` statement. It's far safer to refactor the function like this, which is I think what you were aiming for anyway.

```
char* kangaroo(int x1, int v1, int x2, int v2) {

    int i,k1,k2;
    for(i=0;i<10001;i++)
    {
        k1=x1+(v1*i);
        k2=x2+(v2*i);
        if(k1==k2)
        {
            return "YES";
            // break; this is unreachable 
       }
    }
    return "NO";
}
```